# How to grep URLs from a file, given a reference number?

Tags: grep

Let’s say I have a text file like this: Called it hello

```
1. https://www.google.ca/
2. https://www.bob.ca/
3. https://www.cat.ca/
```

If given the reference number, how would I grep the links?

```
$ grep hello '1.'   # (what should be here to just get the link?)
```

For example I want this to output: https://www.google.ca/ only

Comment: Is it mandatory to use grep ? If not, please consider https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364153/awk-one-liner-select-only-rows-based-on-value-of-a-column

Answer (score 2):

Using only the grep command:

```
grep --perl-regexp --only-matching '(?<=^1\. ).*' hello
```

Some explanations:

- --perl-regexp to activate Perl style regexp
- --only-matching to display only the part that matches
- (?<=^1\. ) means: that is preceded by a line starting with '1. ' ('^' =  'line starting' restriction)

As suggested by [user1404316](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/153769/user1404316), constant '1' can be replaced by a variable:

```
IDX=1
grep --perl-regexp --only-matching "(?<=^${IDX}\. ).*" hello
```

Comment: Two things: 1) I'm not a perl regex person, but shouldn't you be anchoring the `1` to the beginnin of the line so that you don't get false positives for urls with embedded `1`?; 2) Because this answer is a bit complex, and the questioner probably wants something more generally useful, how about replacing `1` with a shell variable and prefixing the grep command with setting that variable, ie. something like `i=1 grep --perl-regexp --only-matching "(?<=^${i}\. ).*" hello`

Answer (score 0):

use sed on pattern (number)  to select line & keep only the part you want : the URL

```
-bash-4.4$ cat > toto
1. https://www.google.ca/
2. https://www.bob.ca/
3. https://www.cat.ca/
-bash-4.4$ sed '/2/ !d ; s/.*\ //' toto
https://www.bob.ca/
-bash-4.4$
```

Answer (score 0):

A normal `grep` in itself only gives you the matching line. Removing the useless part from that is another step.

First, you probably want a pattern more like `^1\.`. The caret forces the match on the beginning of the line, and the backslash makes the dot match only a literal dot, instead of "any character", which is the special meaning of an unescaped dot. Without those, the pattern would match a `1` as part of the URL, or a number `12` at the start of the line, etc.

Then, you need to remove the number at the beginning of the line. `sed` is useful here. `sed` would remove any number of digits, plus a dot, and a space at the start of the line. So we could write this:

```
$ grep -e '^1\.' urls | sed 's/^[0-9]*\. //'
```

But `sed`'s substitution command also works as a condition, this would both try to replace the given number with nothing, and print the resulting line if the replacement was done:

```
$ sed -ne 's/^1\. //p' urls
```

(`-n` means not to print all lines, as is the default behaviour.)

Answer (score 0):

It is simpler using awk:

```
$ awk '"2."==$1{print $2}' hello

https://www.bob.ca/
```

Use any number you choose instead of `2.` to select other lines.

Comment: A more generalized solution that would be useful for scripting would be to pass the search pattern to `awk` as a variable, eg. `search=2 awk -v i="$search" 'i==$1{print $2}' hello`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `egrep` and output only match:

```
grep '^1\.' hello | egrep -o 'http.+'
```

The identifier `1.` is found by searching at the beginning of the line with `^`. Option `-o` will show `--only-matching` and `.+` is a regular expression which will match all characters to end-of-line.